# Connect LED to current limiter TPS259540 and control the current

Tags: fpga, pwm, led-driver, current-limiting, over-current

I have an LED (ILH-ON01) with a forward current (IF) rating of 1 A. I want to operate this LED at a constant current of 1 A using a current limiter. The current limiter I have has a limit of 1.17 A and takes an input voltage of 14 V. To limit the current, I plan to connect a 10 Ω resistor in series with the LED.

Now, I would like to create a "LED driver" that allows me to pulse the enable (EN) signal of the current limiter, so I can control the LED's brightness by varying the duty cycle of the pulses. I intend to use an FPGA to generate these pulses.

My questions are:

The ILH-ON01 LED connect to the output in the right way?

Is it possible to use the enable (EN) signal of the current limiter to control the LED's brightness through pulsing?

Are there any considerations or safety measures I should be aware of to protect the LED and other components while pulsing the enable signal?
[image]

EDIT: If I manage to control the turning off of the LED, it will also help, although it is less good than controlling the current, but it is also a way, will the ENABLE do the job?

Comment: The TPS2595xx is an electronic fuse. While I guess it does, technically, qualify as a current limiter, it's not what I'd choose to drive an LED.

Comment: Why aren't you using a standard controllable current limiter IC which is designed to do the job? The TPS2595xx is designed to be an over current protection device rather than a current limiter. While it may do the job (the enable signal may be a bit slow to respond), I'd use an IC which calls itself an LED current driver or current limiting IC or similar.

Comment: I have a requirement to interface to a given circuit, the cost benefit in this case does not justify it, I am trying to improvise a solution in the given situation, that is why I asked for help, if I can control on/off the LED it will be okay too,

Comment: The EN pin can certainly be used as an on/off switch for the LED. That much should be obvious from the datasheet.

Comment: You're trying to use that complex chip as a simple current regulator. It would make a lot more sense and be much cheaper to buy a simple current regulator rather than pay for a bunch of extra stuff you don't want. Note also the thermal limits on that package, it is meant  only to limit current briefly before you into thermal shutdown.